# VSCode: Execute command automatically on WSL terminal opening

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'd like to execute a command automatically every time I open the WSL terminal on Visual Studio Code (Windows 10).

I'm not using the *Remote WSL extension*, just the WSL terminal with this setting:
`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe"`

I tried unsuccessfully using `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows` setting.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The terminal starts a shell. If it's bash, you can put your command in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @Philippe I'd prefer not to execute this command every time I open the terminal, just when I do it inside VSCode, so if possible making use of the VSCode settings

Comment: VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE doesn't seems to be set in the vscode terminal: could you give me an example of how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux`?

Comment: @x00 yes i tried but it didn't work

Comment: if you use remote wsl there would be a TERM_PROGRAM=vscode env variable. I don't think you can identify it in the current state.

Answer (score 3):

You can put in settings.json:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "-e",
        "bash",
        "--rcfile",
        "/path/to/vscode.bashrc"
    ]
}
```

In vscode.bashrc

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
your-command
```

What's in settings.json asks vscode to run following command :

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe" -e bash --rcfile /path/to/vscode.bashrc
```

`-e` option of wsl runs "bash --rcfile /path/to/vscode.bashrc"

`--rcfile` for bash runs /path/to/vscode.bashrc instead of $HOME/.bashrc

For more details, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Comment: Wow, it's working perfectly, thank you. Can you briefly explain what those arguments do? Or maybe can you suggest a resource that explains it?